# How to go through a collection in jQuery in descending order

Tags: jquery

I have a variable which is,

```
var listItems = GetListItems();

var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var ListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
```

Now Instead of going from top of list to bottom, I want to start from bottom to top,

so I want to get the last item first in `.moveNext()`

Comment: Let's assume, listItem is an object with hundred of properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your code but you can use like this:

```
if(!listItemEnumerator.moveNext().length){
//do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the array first:

```
var listItems = GetListItems();

var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
listItemEnumerator = listItemEnumerator.reverse();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var ListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reverse'  :(

Comment: Oh OK. So GetListItems() returns an object. If listItemEnumerator is an array, then you can reverse that, and Hüseyin BABAL's answer includes a better way of traversal.

Comment: If listItemEnumerator isn't an array, but rather an object that lets you iterate through the listItems, then I would suggest seeing if it's possible to return an array from GetListItems()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reverse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)

```
$.each(listItemEnumerator.reverse(), function(i, rItem) {
    console.log(rItem);
});
```

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GwTBs/)**

Comment: Could you please state the content of `listItemEnumerator` in your question?

Comment: this is what http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410681(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Could you please use `console.log(listItemEnumerator)` and see what prints on console. Object type needed to help you